# how to include google-map in polymer#^2.0 as it was working in polymer 1.7

Tags: google-maps, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have included  api, before everything were working perfect in polymer 1.7, after upgraded to polymer ^2.0 google map does not renders. 
here is my code in main app page written polymer class base:

```
<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404">  
  <jj-maps name="maps"  user="{{user}}" sprof="{{sprof}}"></jj-maps>
  <jj-list name="list" >    Jobs   </jj-list>  
  <jj-infos name="infos">    infos      </jj-infos>
  <jj-contacts name="contacts" >  Contacts  </jj-contacts>
  <jj-messages name="messages">  Messages  </jj-messages>
  <jj-404 name="404" > 404          </jj-404>
</iron-pages>
```

at jj-maps.html code sample is :

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-marker.html">
```

style codes in template tag:

```
<dom-module id="jj-maps">
  <template>
    <style  include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
      :host {
       .....
       google-map, #mapResults {
           margin-top: 10px;
           position: relative;
           height: 100vh;
           width: 100vh%; 
           z-index: 1;
       }
```

....

```
       <div id="mapResults"> 
         <google-map 
                  id="map" 
                  map="{{map}}" 
                  latitude="[[latitude]]" 
                  longitude="[[longitude]]" 
                  zoom="10"
                  api-key="[[myApiKey]]"  
                  on-google-map-ready= '_mapLoaded' 
                  additional-map-options='{"gestureHandling" : "greedy"}'
                  >
                 <google-map-marker map="{{map}}" slot="marker" latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}"
                      title="You are here !" icon="./src/image/gpslocc.png" draggable="true">
                 </google-map-marker>
                 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sprof}}" as="item">
                        <google-map-marker map="[[map]]" slot="marker" latitude="[[item.myLat]]" longitude="[[item.myLng]]" animation="DROP"  click-events  title="{{item.prof}}" icon="{{calculateIconType(item.isFree)}}" on-google-map-marker-click='showUserDetail' userid="[[item.uid]]" isFree="{{item.isFree}}" >
                        </google-map-marker>

                 </template>
                 <paper-fab icon="maps:my-location" on-tap="updateCurrentPosition"></paper-fab>
                </google-map>
        </div>

  </template>
```

this code works perfect in previous polymer. And Another point when I bower install the dependencies as `bower install --save GoogleWebComponents/google-map`

bower asks me for two as :

```
 - Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below: 
 I chose :  7) polymer#^2.0.0 which resolved to 2.0.1 and is required by myApp
    - Unable to find a suitable version for webcomponentsjs, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
I chose : 2) webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0 which resolved to 1.0.1 and is required by myApp
```

Sorry in advance that I ve written detailed codes. Meanwhile I have tried many options but could not able to render map in my jj-maps elements (class base template, even I have tried legacy template (as same as polymer 1.7 ver)

Here is is console warning :

```
dom-module.html:24 dom-module google-map has style outside template
dom-module google-map-marker has style outside template
```

Maps are not rendering...

So, how to solve ? Thanks in advance. (previous polymer ver. working at jobijoy.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having exactly same issue. Tried to add slot="marker" to google-map-marker as someone suggested [Polymer 2.0 issue in github](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/360) but doesn't work for me. It looks like the google-map component's size is set to 0 by 0 thus does not display at all. Since the google components are not updated to be compatible with Polymer 2.0. I've manually updated my local google-map.html and google-map-marker.html files under bower_component folder and moved the style tags into the template tags. The warnings are gone and the map displays now. I guess we have to wait for the update of the google components for things to work properly. I hope this helps.

Comment: When I included style tags under template tags in google-map, its render now. :)) Thank you !

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Comment: `google-map` element is updated to Polymer version 2.0. All elements managed by Polymer team are updated. You just have to install them with affix `#2.0-preview`

Answer (score 0):

```
slot="marker"
```

should solve the issue.

Unfortunately the example in the code does not insert this important line.

Here is the without slot="markers" current code example:

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fit-to-markers>
    <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892" draggable="true" title="Go Giants!">
    </google-map-marker>
    <google-map-marker latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911">
    </google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

And below the suggested corrected example that should be inside the code:

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fit-to-markers>
    <google-map-marker slot="markers" latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892" draggable="true" title="Go Giants!">
    </google-map-marker>
    <google-map-marker slot="markers" latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911">
    </google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

What is happening?

google-map does not know when markers are inserted or updated because without the attribute slot="markers" they are inserted outside the slot where they should be inserted in.

Several consequences can happen from this issue: the map can be viewed, but not respond to important events, like fit-to-markers.

In these turbulent moves from original without-slots version to the current slotted version (and soon moving to polymer 3.0 version) of the excellent google-map webcomponent, there is a high chance that the busy developers simply forgot to add this important slot="markers" attribute in the example that shows how to add each new google-map-marker webcomponent inside google-map.

This only complements the already correct above answer. If anyone needed more explanation, I offer these, If I am correct, of course (please correct me if I made wrong conclusions).

You can detect this flaw inspecting your google-map element. Without the slot="markers" correction, open google-map; inside it, open iron-selector; and finally inside it open the element `<slot id="markers" name="markers"><slot>`. If you do not use the suggested correction, this slot will be empty. If you use this suggested correction, this slot will contain references to each google-map-marker. And so the google-map element will be able to handle several events that rely on detecting when each marker is inserted or updated.

Sorry for the long answer.

Comment: Seems even I put the <google-map-marker slot="markers" still couldn't show. but all doms are rendered, don't know why