# Can't get google-map marker to render (Polymer 2.0)

Tags: google-maps, polymer

I can't seem to get google-map-marker to display in my  element.

This is what I've got:

*View.html*

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-marker.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-directions.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-poly.html">

<google-map fit-to-marker disable-default-ui api-key="****" zoom="8" latitude="57.1071180" longitude="12.2520910">
    <google-map-marker latitude="57.1071180" longitude="12.2520910">
         <p>test Div</p> 
    </google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

I only included the google maps specific stuff.

The version of the google-map web component is 1.2.0

Now, this is what I get:

[image: The marker should be at "varberg"]

And this is what developer tools has:

[image]

Any help or ideas as to why it doesn't render would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to include google-map in polymer#^2.0 as it was working in polymer 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607665/how-to-include-google-map-in-polymer2-0-as-it-was-working-in-polymer-1-7)

Comment: Ew, screenshot-ed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607665/how-to-include-google-map-in-polymer2-0-as-it-was-working-in-polymer-1-7)  As I have solved this before. In case of any unclear point, feel free to ask again. 
Here also [source](https://github.com/RoXuS/google-map) of my solution

As briefly; 
You need 2 small changes both google-map and google-map-marker.

1. Replace or correct `slot` at both element ( `google-map`, and
       `google-map-marker` )     [shown as](https://github.com/RoXuS/google-map/commit/361d3896778f224af76e3cb88a141733b9f7f445#diff-3df3a2c83cdee5d2b2cbfab6208ba2b4)
2. Move style tag  inside just after `template`